# Query produced for IN filter on 1-1 relation joins to parent table twice

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this problem and reproduced it with AdventureWorks2008R2 to make it more easy. Basically, I want to filter a parent table for a list of IN values and I thought it would generate this type of query 
but it doesn't.

```
SELECT * FROM SalesOrderDetail where EXISTS( select * from SalesOrderHeader where d.id=h.id and rowguid IN ('asdf', 'fff', 'weee' )
```

**Any ideas how to change the LINQ statement to query Header only once?**

(ignore the fact I'm matching on Guids - it will actually be integers; I was just quickly looking for a 1-1 table in EF because that's when the problem occurs and I happened to find these)

```
var guidsToFind = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()};
AdventureWorks2008R2Entities context = new AdventureWorks2008R2Entities();
var g = context.People.Where(p => guidsToFind.Contains(p.BusinessEntity.rowguid)).ToList();
```

That produces the following more expensive query:

```sql
SELECT [Extent1].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID], 
[Extent1].[PersonType] AS [PersonType], 
[Extent1].[NameStyle] AS [NameStyle], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[Suffix] AS [Suffix], 
[Extent1].[EmailPromotion] AS [EmailPromotion], 
[Extent1].[AdditionalContactInfo] AS [AdditionalContactInfo], 
[Extent1].[Demographics] AS [Demographics], 
[Extent1].[rowguid] AS [rowguid], 
[Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate]
FROM   [Person].[Person] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntity] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BusinessEntityID] = [Extent2].[BusinessEntityID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Person].[BusinessEntity] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[BusinessEntityID] = [Extent3].[BusinessEntityID]
WHERE [Extent2].[rowguid] = cast('b95b63f9-6304-4626-8e70-0bd2b73b6b0f' as uniqueidentifier) OR [Extent3].[rowguid] IN (cast('f917a037-b86b-4911-95f4-4afc17433086' as uniqueidentifier),cast('3188557d-5df9-40b3-90ae-f83deee2be05' as uniqueidentifier))
```

Answer (score 0):

Really odd. Looks like a LINQ limitation.

I don't have a system to try this on right now but if you first get a list of BusinessEntityId values based on the provided guids and then get the persons like this

```
var g = context.People.Where(p => businessEntityIdList.Contains(p.BusinessEntityId)).ToList();
```

there should not be a reason for additional unnecessary joins anymore.

If that works, you can try to combine the to steps into one LINQ expression to see if the separation stays intact.

Comment: I was going to say that did not help because it's the same linq statement I gave.  but it did give me the idea of manually joining the 2 tables with LINQ and the join word. It works for this case but it cripples Any other ideas? :D